# Question regarding present value with discount rate

Tags: accounting

I am a novice at finance subjects and need to find out Present value given a few details

The university fees of $45,000 a year will have be paid starting 11 years from today. He is analysing an insurance plan that pays out $45,000 a year for 4 years with the first payout 11 years from today. The insurance plan has several payment options:

Option 1
Pay $60,000 today

Option 2
Beginning 1 year from today, pay $12,000 a year for the next 8 years

Option 3
Beginning 1 year from today, make payments each year for the next 8 years. The first payment is $11,000 and the amount increases by 5% each year

The question is asking to calculate Present Value for each option with a 10% discount rate.

I understand that PV = FV / (1 + r)^t

Am I right to say that FV is $180,000, r is 0.1 and t is 11 years?
And if so, Option 1 PV = $180000 / 1.1^11 = $63088.90

But I am stucked for Option 2 and 3, how do I move on from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer for the PV of the insurance is not right. You need to discount each of the 4 payments separately since they occur at different times. So the total PV would be

```
  45,000 / (1.1)^11  
+ 45,000 / (1.1)^12 
+ 45,000 / (1.1)^13 
+ 45,000 / (1.1)^14
--------------------
  54,995
```

For 2 and 3, find the PV of each option and compare it to the PV of the insurance plan. You'll need to calculate the PV of each *cash flow* separately. So the answer to #2 would be

```
  12,000 / (1.1)^1  
+ 12,000 / (1.1)^2 
+ 12,000 / (1.1)^3 
...
```

and 3 would be

```
  11,000            / (1.1)^1  
+ 11,000 * (1.05)^1 / (1.1)^2 
+ 11,000 * (1.05)^2 / (1.1)^3 
...
```

Comment: I have calculated and obtained the following Option 1 - $54995, Option 2 - $64019, Option 3 - $68366, since Option 1 has the lowest value, am I safe to say that John should choose Option 1 since the PV is lower hence translating to a higher discount?

Comment: Actually Option 1 is "pay 60k now" but yes that is the cheapest option. The insurance is a required expense, so you'd pick the financing method that has the lowest current cost which would be Option 1.

Comment: So the value of $54995 is just a calculated value and the real PV is $60k for Option 1?

Comment: The $54,995 is the PV of the insurance contract. The three options are different ways to _purchase_ that contract. You'd choose the one that has the lowest current cost.